# How can I change the name of migration database in database array?

Tags: migrations

For a Drupal migration from d7 to d8, I have to define my source database to be called 'migrate' in the settings.php as below. My question is: how can I define the source as something other than 'migrate',  where is that set up?

```
`$databases['default']['default'] = array(
  'database' => "db",
  'username' => "db",
  'password' => "db",
  'host' => $host,
  'driver' => "mysql",
  'port' => $port,
  'prefix' => "",
);


$databases['migrate']['default'] = array(
  'database' => "drupal7",
  'username' => "db",
  'password' => "db",
  'host' => $host,
  'driver' => "mysql",
  'port' => $port,
  'prefix' => "",
);`
```

Comment: Probably in the migrate module. Probably hard-coded. Why would you need to have it named differently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`migrate` is the default key used by the `SqlBase` class which is the base for the D7 source plugins. [Its documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21migrate%21src%21Plugin%21migrate%21source%21SqlBase.php/class/SqlBase/8.8.x) explains in detail how it determines what key to use and how it can be changed. Of relevance:

> As described above, the default source database is $databases['migrate']. If the source plugin needs another source connection, the database connection parameters should be added to the $databases array as, for instance, $databases['foo']. The source plugin can then use this connection by setting 'key' to 'foo' in its configuration.

So update the `source.key` value in your migration configuration to `foo` then re-import that configuration to change the default key used for that migration source.